# Parent Activity killed after launching camera

Tags: android

Consider this scenario.
1.)onCreate - find the background imageview's height and width and do some math for creating child imageviews where camera taken photos are put. However, I am adding a callback from `ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener` because I can't get it's width and height.

2.)makes an intent to launch the camera

```
Intent intent = new Intent(
                android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
```

In the camera when I press ok to return to onActivityResult on my activity. My activity gets killed and onCreate is fired again.

Sequence triggered

```
onCreate

onActivityResult 

ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener
```

I get null pointer because my child views were not yet created.

I'm suppose to take 3 camera images in the activity. So I don't know how I should persist the taken photos on the imageviews. How do I manage this?

Answer (score 0):

Passing/Persisting bitmaps in between android life cycle is cumbersome. I just use a static class to store the bitmaps and recycle them appropriately if not needed